# How to make a panel pop up when selecting a game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a panel with some buttons on that I want to be visible only when a cube game object is clicked on.

I have tried doing this unsuccessfully so please could anyone give me some advice.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

on your cube script:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
      popUp.setActive(true)
}
```

Comment: Why should he use that?